# Node server CPU stays high after requests no longer sent

Tags: node.js

I have a Node server with Apollo and a few other dependencies.

I'm encountering an issue where sending ~100-200 RPM to the server causes a raise in CPU to around 80-90%, but after we stop sending requests, the CPU stays around 80-90%.

To isolate the issue, I tried commenting out different code areas, such as JWT, Optimizley and testing again, but there was no change.

Tried to isolate a specific API, but this happens for all API calls. Also updated various packages + upgraded from Node 14 to 16.

Increased CPU and Memory, doubled CPU but still same behavior happens.
Nothing made a difference.

Was wondering in what additional ways I can tackle this?

Comment: I think that what you're looking for is called "CPU profiling"

Comment: Familiar with that, but cannot currently access files on the docker itself. So no way to read the output. Anything else I can try?

Comment: I don't know your setup, but usually apps have a dev mode (which relaunches the app when changes are made in the source) that can be run directly from the code without using docker, and I would suggest trying to reproduce in your dev setup and profile there. If your setup requires docker, you can `docker exec` and `docker cp` to run profiling and copy the files

Comment: its more of an AWS issue than a docker, waiting for this to be resolved. But for now, need to find a different way to find the root cause.

Comment: So you're unable to reproduce locally? Could be tough, then. Might be worth adding something like New Relic or a web profiler, if only temporarily.

Comment: I have newrelic but no indication in the logs, any where I can check in newrelic?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used that... All I can offer is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEMuDzZ3XKg  good luck